# What is causing a 3rd party domain object to throw an exception when saving in Javers/Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, javers

I am using javers 6.2.5 and Spring Boot 2.5.2. I am getting an IllegalArgumentException saying "argument should not be null". It is being thrown in GlobalIdFactory.createId(). I have figured out that one of our 3rd party domain objects is causing the issue as once I replaced it with just a String, everything works fine. Since it is a 3rd party domain object I obviously cannot change that object. Can anybody explain what the error is and how I could fix it?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, because I don't see the stack trace and code, but it looks like it's mapped as Entity and it has null Id. In that case it can't be saved to Javers. Try to change its mapping to Value Object.